# Can't reference array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array defined as:

```
var subjectCache = [];
```

I then have some code to build it up, which is working ok.

However, if I try to reference the array by an index, e.g.:

```
var x = subjectCache[0];
```

or

```
var x = subjectCache[1];
```

I get `undefined`.
Also `subjectCache.length` is always 0 (zero).

if I try to reference it by its key, e.g.:

```
var x = subjectCache['12345'];
```

it works.

Is this normal? Shouldn't I be able to reference it by its index whatever?

I'm using Internet Explorer, if it makes a difference (and it probably does :( )

[Edit]

this is the code I'm using to build the array, although I really don't think it is to blame.

It's a callback from a webservice call. This is working fine and the array is being populated.

```
var subjectCache = [];
var subjectCacheCount = 0;

function refreshSubjectsCallback(data) {
    // update subjects
    // loop through retrieved subjects and add to cache
    for( i=0; i < data.length; i++ )
    {
        var subject = data[i];
        var subjectid = subject.SubjectId;
        subjectCache[subjectid] = subject;
        subjectCacheCount += 1;
    }
}
```

[/Edit]

Comment: What code do you use to build your array up?

Comment: Can you post some code that shows how you're adding items to the array? What version of internet explorer? And have you tested on any other browser?

Comment: I ensure you, this time it has nothing to do with IE.

Comment: It's not possible for an array to have a property with key `12345` and a `.length` of zero. Please post a demo on e.g. jsFiddle.

Comment: Seems like you are using non-numerical keys for arrays. Don't do that, use objects instead arrays then. Arrays only really work with numerical keys.

Comment: It is important to know what kind of data `SubjectId` is. Is it indeed an index meant for an array (i.e. a whole number `>= 0`)?

Comment: Basically, everyone was pretty much right. Thanks for the help

Comment: Any reason for the vote down?

Comment: I think you were voted down because the issue is not reproducible. Also, you didn't mention some important information (what is `SubjectId`).

Comment: Related post - [JavaScript array index 'undefined' in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14070442/465053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably assigning keys manually instead of using `subjectCache.push()` to add new elements to the array:

```
var array = [];

array['foo'] = 'bar';

console.log(array.length);  // 0
```

The `length` attribute isn't going to reflect those changes the way you'd expect:

```
> var a = [];
undefined
> a[100] = 2;  // The previous `100` entries evaluate to `undefined`
2
> a.length;
101
```

Instead, use an object:

```
var object = {};

object['foo'] = 'bar';

for (var key in object) {
    var value = object[key];

    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your symptoms, it sounds like you are trying to treat the array as an associative array.

In Javascript, arrays work like this:

```
var a = [];
a[1] = 10;
alert(a.length);
```

Objects work like this:

```
var o = {};
o.myProp = true;
o["myOtherProp"] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays only work with numeric keys not strings. Strings assign properties to the object, and aren't counted as part of `length` nor it's numeric indices.

When building the array, make sure you are assigning to a numeric position within the array.

Comment: This is not correct here I'm afraid. `arr[12345]` is the same as `arr['12345']`.

Comment: *Numeric* strings are considered though (because all property names are internally stored as strings anyway).

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work, because you haven't created arrays but objects.
you will have to access it by its key.

```
var x = subjectCache['12345'];
```

If this works and `subjectCache.length` doesn't, I think you are making an **object** not an array. You are confused.

Comment: `[]` does create an array, and `arr['12345']` works the same way as `arr[12345]`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the road you lost the array, and the variable `subjectCache` points to a different kind of object.

If it was an array, it can't have the length zero and contain an item that is reachable using `subjectCache['12345']`. When you access an item in an array it doesn't make any difference if you use a numeric index or a string representing a number.