# JavaScript array index 'undefined' in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

The following script prints *undefined* to the console for each character in the string, but works correctly in Chrome.

```
<script>
function main()
{
    var x = "hello world";
    for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i ) {
        console.log( x[i] );
    }
}
main();
</script>
```

Do I have to do something to the array in order to get this to work properly in all browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[]` is supported in some browsers but not all:

> Array-like character access (the second way above) is not part of
>   ECMAScript 3. It is a JavaScript and ECMAScript 5 feature.

For maximum compatibility, use [`String.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) instead:

```
<script>
function main()
{
    var x = "hello world";
    for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i ) {
        console.log( x.charAt(i) );
    }
}
main();
</script>
```

Comment: IE8 does support `[]` perfectly also for string, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of IE don't support the array notation (`string[x]`) to access strings, use: [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) instead.

```
<script>
    function main() {
        var x = "hello world";
        for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i ) {
            console.log( x.charAt(i) );
        }
    }
    main();
</script>
```

Also, if you're directly executing your function, you could as well create a self-executing anonymous function (to preserve the scope / not pollute the global namespace)

```
<script>
    (function main() {
        var x = "hello world";
        for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i ) {
            console.log( x.charAt(i) );
        }
    }());
</script>
```

Unless you have to run it from somewhere else also, of course.

Comment: IE8 does support it perfectly, see my answer

Comment: @MarcoDemaio: [IE8 also supports `console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log)

Comment: Then how am I logging in IE8? Simple: the IE developer tools are way older than IE 10.
OP is talking about a _"JavaScript array index undefined"_. That has _nothing_ to do with the console.

Comment: `console` object is only IE10, I tested this, or see Microsoft reference if you don't trust: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772192(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Dude, I'm running IE8 here and logging stuff to the console as we speak. Also, the user says _"prints `undefined` to the **console**"_

MS can tell me the console object doesn't exist 'till IE10, but they've been wrong before. I'm `console.log()`-ing to all my delight in IE8, and there's nothing MSDN can do about that.

Comment: `charAt` anyway is not needed, `[]` works in IE8+ so unless OP uses IE7 I don't understand why it says it does not work.

Comment: @MarcoDemaio Maybe OP is running the page in Quirks-mode, then `[]` won't work.

Answer (score -1):

It's `console` the problem here. This object does not exist in IE Javascript engine.

If you do this it works in both

```
<script>
function main()
{
    var x = "hello world", result = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i )
       result += x[i];
    document.write(result); //it prints "hello world" on page
}
main();
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

- `console` object does not exists until IE10 (as correctly noted by Cerbrus, unless you turn on the IE developer tool, in such case it exists also on IE8)
- `[]` to access strings chars can be used in IE8+ (on IE7 it does not work yet)

Comment: Try to run this on IE versions that don't support `console.log`. They won't support array-like access of strings, either.

Comment: IE7 does not support my code, but I suppose user is not still using IE7. Anyway I updated the answer, still IE8, IE9 and IE10 DO ALL SUPPORT `[]`, they do not need `charAt`. That's why I suppose the user issue is with `console.log` here.

Comment: _The following script prints undefined to the console_. There _is_ a console :)

Comment: Correction to your edit: The `console` does exits in IE8/9 if the user has the development tools installed.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the following code, try to increase TimeOut value to maximum...

```
window.setTimeOut('Your Js function(), 150)
```

Now, it increase to

```
window.setTimeOut('Your Js function(), 2000)
```