# Javascript array access in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've a HTML code snippet like follows:

```
<form>
  <select name="mySelect">
    <option value="1">text_1</option>
    <option value="2">text_2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I found out that in Internet Explorer, Javascript below can work:

```
document.forms[0].mySelect.options(0).text
```

But in Firefox or Chrome, it can not work and reports such error message:

```
document.forms[0].mySelect.options is not a function
```

In my opinion, mySelect.options should be an array, thus must be accessed by mySelect.options[0]. I also checked the DOM api and found no options function available.

Does it mean in the IE javascript engine, all arrays can be treated as both a collection and a function? Any advice will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `document.forms[0].mySelect.options[0]`

Comment: Because IE confuses property access with method calls, use square brackets: `...options[0].text`

Comment: It should be noted that referring to a form via document.forms[0] is a bad idea in principle as it will break the moment you decide to add another form to that page (like a login form, or a sidebar form).  Much better off to use document.getElementById( 'FORMID' ).mySelect...

Comment: @TomMcQuarrie, thanks! Actually I know forms[0] is a bad idea and for me I only use JQuery to ignore such browser differences. This is a snippet from a legacy project which causes me a bit confused.

Comment: Related post - [JavaScript array index 'undefined' in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14070442/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, that `options` is not an array, it's [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is an array-like object. This is also a host object, hence it can behave differently from JS objects.

In IE you can call HTMLCollection as it was a function (at least in older IEs):

```
select.options(vIndex [, iSubIndex] );
```

Here `vIndex` is either an integer representing an index, or a string referring `name` property. As you can have multiple similar names, `iSubIndex` is used to construct a collection of all elements that have a name or id property equal to the string, and then retrieves from this collection the element at the position specified by `iSubIndex`.

Comment: noted and thanks, actually I also tested on IE11 and it can work. Guess IE also sticks to its tradition, :)